# Mat-Select Angular option filter for user type 3-4 character

Tags: angular, mat-select

I want to highlight/jump to the option based on the user type character on the keyboard.
By default, it only takes for first character. but i want that if user type 3-4 character then it should jump to the option starting with those typed 3-4 character.
E.G there are thousands of mat-option in mat-select and when user type "flo" then the highlight should jump to the first option starting with "flo"

```
<h4>mat-select</h4>
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
  <mat-label>State</mat-label>
  <mat-select>
    <mat-option>None</mat-option>
    <mat-option *ngFor="let state of states" [value]="state">{{state}}</mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts file code

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/** @title Select with reset option */
@Component({
  selector: 'select-reset-example',
  templateUrl: 'select-reset-example.html',
})
export class SelectResetExample {
  states: string[] = [
    'Alabama', 'Alaska', 'Arizona', 'Arkansas', 'California', 'Colorado', 'Connecticut', 'Delaware',
    'Florida', 'Georgia', 'Hawaii', 'Idaho', 'Illinois', 'Indiana', 'Iowa', 'Kansas', 'Kentucky',
    'Louisiana', 'Maine', 'Maryland', 'Massachusetts', 'Michigan', 'Minnesota', 'Mississippi',
    'Missouri', 'Montana', 'Nebraska', 'Nevada', 'New Hampshire', 'New Jersey', 'New Mexico',
    'New York', 'North Carolina', 'North Dakota', 'Ohio', 'Oklahoma', 'Oregon', 'Pennsylvania',
    'Rhode Island', 'South Carolina', 'South Dakota', 'Tennessee', 'Texas', 'Utah', 'Vermont',
    'Virginia', 'Washington', 'West Virginia', 'Wisconsin', 'Wyoming'
  ];
}
```

Current Behaviour
=> if user types "flo" then it jumps first with the option starting with "f" then with "l" and finally it highlight /focus the first option starting with "o".

Expected Behaviour
=> if user types "flo" then it should jumps/highlights to the first option starting with "flo"

Tried Examples
`keydown="$event.stopPorpogation"`

Any solution to achive the Expected Behaviour

Answer (score 0):

```
typeaheadDebounceInterval="500" or typeaheadDebounceInterval="1000"
```

added the above attribute to the mat-select and then it works

Comment: This solution is not as good as the native element.
If you type "flo" it will highlight to the match option after 1 second, may be that will be okay. But lets say you have lots of option starting with "f" then, just to navigate between those, simply pressing "f" will highlight after a second each time. Unlike native select option. Any solution to achieve that, is what I need. Please share if you found.
When type may highlight immediately the option starting with pressed key, but will take second key-pressed also into consideration, if pressed within 1 second